# Value obtained from listening to a stream not updating class variable

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have a simple class called UserProvider that listens to a User stream on initialisation and then updates the variable `currentUser` to the value gotten from the stream.

The problem is, for some weird reason, when I set the value of currentUser to the value obtained from the stream, it isn't updated in the class. It is only updated in the `userStream.listen` method.

How can I fix this?

```
class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  User currentUser;

  UserProvider() {
    this.listenToUserStream();
  }

  void listenToUserStream() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((FirebaseUser firUser) {
      if (firUser != null) {
        Stream<User> userStream = UserService().getUserInfoAsStream();
        userStream.listen((event) {
          this.currentUser = event;
          print(currentUser); // prints instance of User;
          notifyListeners();
        });
      } else {
        this.currentUser = null;
      }
      print(currentUser); // prints null;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this class is not a singleton, so if you are using multiple instances of this class it could cause some issues.

Comment: Yes, it isn't a singleton, but that doesn't affect the problem at all. I'm only using a single instance of the class at the moment, so I'm not concerned about multiple instances for now.

Comment: It might help to see where the class is being used. Sometimes a class can get recreated in a build method if you are not careful.